# Can you use subdirectories within Jekyll's _includes folder?

Tags: html, ruby, gulp, jekyll

My plan is to have folders within the `_includes` directory:

_includes/footers

_includes/heros

_includes/cta

etc...

When I reference that `{% include footers/footer1.html %}` I get the following error:

`Liquid Exception: Included file '_includes/footers/footer1.html' not found in _layouts/default.html`

Is this outside the intended functionality, or am I missing something?

Comment: This is supposed to work. Do you have some sources on github ?

Comment: This works for me! Check file permissions and ensure the file `_includes/footers/footer1.html` is there.

Answer (score 12):

Yes you can nest partials. Subdirectories don't have to be prepended with an underscore.

Let's say you have a `footers` folder inside the `_includes` folder.

```
_includes/footers
```

You could include your resources by adding the relative path:

```
{% include footers/footer1.html %}
```

Answer (score 2):

On `jekyll 3.0.1` you don't have to use `_` to prepend directories in `_includes`. 
I have a structure like `_includes/foo/file.html, _includes/bar/file.html` and I use it like `{% include foo/file.html %}` and `{% include bar/file.html %}`. It works perfectly fine without underscores. This might be a behavior that is not present in other versions of Jekyll.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of those scenarios where I came back to it, seemingly tried the exact same thing, and it worked.

---

- You can use subdirectories within _layout folders
- You don't have to use underscores for it to work (Perhaps this is just a best, practice?)